# Protractor not waiting for modal

Tags: protractor, bootstrap-modal, wait

I have a modal that shows up in a protractor test. When I run the test case solo, it works perfectly, but when I run it as part of the larger file (currently 10 cases, some lengthy) it slows things down and, as a result, the modal is slower to open and close. The chain effect is that, when I try to click on a button on the page, it crashes since the modal (which was supposed to be closed by now) is still there and blocking the button.

How can I properly sense when the modal is open/closed so that I can work around this?

Thanks!

(Also, this is an AngularJS application)

Comment: So if this modal is a window (not sure) you could adapt your function from last week to do a wait for the number of windows to be (at least) one less than it was when the window was open. If the modal is an alert, you do wait for EC.not(EC.alertIsPresent)).

Comment: I don't think it's a window and I'm not sure how to implement ExpectedConditions (I'm still relatively a newcomer to Protractor)

Comment: I'm making this a comment not an answer since it's not REALLY an answer. I sidestepped the issue by putting the use case in question higher up in the file. This way, the script is not backed up on itself by the time it gets there. Not really a solution. More of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

These are my helper functions for manual waiting:

```
    static async forElementAbsent(element) {
    return await new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        browser.driver.wait(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element), 10000,
            `Timed out waiting for element to be absent`).then(() => {
                resolve();
            });
    });
}

static async forElementPresent(element) {
    return await new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        browser.driver.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element), 10000,
            `Timed out waiting for element to be present`).then(() => {
                resolve();
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In our tests, we are waiting for modals to be displayed manually. We have helper functions such as

```
export async function forCondition(condition: () => boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>, timeout = 20000): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    return await browser.wait(condition, timeout);
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Given function waits for a condition to fullfill. So in your particular case you would have to find out the css selector of the modal which is displayed. 
Let's say the selector is `by.css('.modal.visible')`, then we would have to write something like the following if we wanted to wait for the modal to be displayed:

```
t.it('modal should be displayed', async function() {
  // wait for modal to be displayed
  var result = await forCondition(function() { 
    return element(by.css('.modal.visible')).isDisplayed();
  });

  expect(result).toBeTruthy();
});
```